# GParted black screen after waking up

Tags: live-cd, gparted

I am running `GParted` with a live CD 11.04. Since it's a long job the screen goes into power save mode. When I move the mouse the screen comes back but the display is black and the cursor looks like the editing cursor (I shape). I think the process is still running because I can see the HD light blinking. It's been more than a day that the process is running so I was wondering if there is a way to know the status because the black screen with the editing cursor looks like a freeze. Is there a way to refresh the screen?

**UPDATE**

In a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> I ran the command `sudo fdisk -l` and for the HD I partitioned I got:

```
/dev/sdb1 * 1 120901 971128832 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2  120901 121538 5118976 5 Extended 
/dev sdb3  121538 121602 513024 83 Linux
/dev/sdb5  120901 121538 5117952 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

The partitioning I asked for was:

```
Primary of around 950 GB (don't remember the exact number)
Extended for the swap of 5 GB
```

I feel that `GParted` is done but I want to make sure before rebooting the system. What do you think?

Comment: GParted can take a very long time to complete. I just resized a partition on a new computer and it took more than 24 hours. I am not that knowledgeable in this area but I would suggest to wait till the HDD activity ceases and see if the GParted window is no longer black then. I mean, if the data on the partition is valuable to you it makes sense to take the time to wait.

Comment: I'll wait for sure, the HD activity is a good sign. I was just asking because I have to get status update on the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no HD activity anymore and with the result of `sudo fsidk -l`. I decided to reboot the system and everything is working. So `GParted` actually finished the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try using iotop to see if the blinking hdd is actually meaningful or not.
Also, htop is good to see if gparted has any child processes running.

I don't think gparted actually does anything, it just runs other processes, but I don't know this for sure.

In case you're not aware, you can definitely install packages on the livecd all you want.

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
sudo apt-get install htop
```